# How to make a photoshop style clipping mask with two divs

Tags: html, css, mask, clipping

I  have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/r8sqt6yc/3/) code and I want to have the .clip box to create a clipping mask effect to the .ml so that the part of the line above 50vh is black, and as users scroll the line appears to be turning black.

```
.clip{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #414141;
    clip: auto;
}
```

Comment: Unsure of what you are actually trying to ask here...

Comment: sorry about that, just wondering how to make the black box clip to the grey line as it scrolls through it

Comment: Oooh, so you don't want there to be a black box, just a line thats half black and half grey?

Comment: i would do like this http://jsfiddle.net/r8sqt6yc/4/ ... here or even like this http://jsfiddle.net/r8sqt6yc/5/ but i do not think this could be your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe with background-attachment:fixed ?

```css
.dualbg {
  height:100vh;
  background:linear-gradient(to top, #333,#333) no-repeat rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-size:100% 50%;
  width:3px;
  margin:50vh auto 0;
  background-attachment:fixed;
```

```html
<div class="dualbg"></div>
```